# Mamp pro install php 8

Tags: php, mamp, mamp-pro, php-8

I have a MAMP PRO version 5.6 installed on my Mac.

I need to add php-8 version to my Mamp.

Can't find a solution. Please advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

You don't have to 'add' it to your MAMP since it's already there.
Take a look at your MAMP, then find PHP menu on the sidebar, then select the default version of it.

See below:

[image: MAMP Pro Selecting PHP Version]

And you also could selecting PHP version per-project.

[image: Selecting PHP per Project]

Comment: It shows up to version 7.4 for me, no 8.x versions there.

Comment: Hello @Simon, I mean if you take a closer look at my first screenshot, there is a small "+" button next to the form field "Default Version". You should be able to just easily download the version do you want. Let me know if that helps you and mark the answer as the correct one!